# jQuery click event doesn't execute two times

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a button in my page which basically returns an alert as a sample. The button fires only one time. I checked previous entries and changed to event. The current event is like below

```
  $("#save_button").on("click", "#save", function() {
    alert("Button clickeddddd");

  });
```

the html is as below

```
>     <body>
>         
>     <div data-role="page" data-theme='b'>
> 
> 
>         <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme='b'>
>             <a href="index.html" data-ajax="false"><i class='icon-tablet icon-medium'></i></a>
>             <h1>Languages</h1>
>         </div>
>         
>         <div data-role="content">   
> 
>               
>             <form>
>                 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">  
>                   
>                     <li data-role="fieldcontain">
>                         <label for="language" class="select">Language:</label>
>                         <select name="language" id="language" data-native-menu="true">
>                             <option value="en">English</option>
>                             <option value="de">German</option>
>                         </select>
>                     </li>
> 
>                     <li>
>                         <fieldset class="ui-grid-solo" id="save_button">
>                                 <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="submit" data-theme="b" id="save">Save</button></div>
>                         </fieldset>
>                     </li>
>                 </ul>
>             </form>
>           
>         </div>
> 
>       <div data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false"
> data-role="footer" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme='b'>            <div
> data-role="navbar">
>               <ul>
>                   <li><a href="languages.html" data-icon="globe" id="languages"></a></li>
>                   <li><a href="themes.html" data-icon="eye-open" id="themes"></a></li>
>                   <li><a href="settings.html" data-icon="cog" id="settings"></a></li>
>                   <li><a href="login.html" data-icon="signin" id="login"></a></li>
>               </ul>           </div>      </div>
> 
>     </div>
>     
>     </body> </html>
```

I tried to use the id="save_button" in several places (div : all levels), li, ul, form etc. in every place the event works only one time. afterwards it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could delegate event to document level to handle any dynamic element:

```
$(document).on("click", "#save", function() {
    alert("Button clickeddddd");

  });
```

Please read: 

### jQuery delegation